# bash parallel run multiple times with shell variables

Tags: bash, macos, for-loop, parallel-processing

I have a bash script (on Mac) and need to run a program called program multiple times (say 10) with 3 arguments: 1 parameter text file (pars) and two shell variables that I want to change in a for loop.

I don't seem to get the nitty gritty quotation marks right.

```
#!/bin/bash

export FIRST=1.8
export STEP=0.1
export LAST=2.0
export PAR1=78

export nprocs=$( sysctl -n hw.ncpu )

for PAR2 in $(seq $FIRST $STEP $LAST);
do      
    parallel --jobs $nprocs ./program pars $PAR1 $PAR2 ::: {0..10}

    wait
done
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean like: `parallel --jobs $nprocs -- ./program pars $PAR1 $PAR2 ::: {{0..10}}` Making sure those curly braces are expanded by shell and not read as an argument of `parallel`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need `wait` because you are not starting any jobs in the background.

Secondly, if you don't want to pass the parameters 0..10 to your program, use:

```
parallel -n 0 ...
```

Comment: I am not at a machine currently to check, but I think your `nprocs` is redundant as it is probably the same as the number of CPU cores which is what **GNU Parallel** uses anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash

export FIRST=1.8
export STEP=0.1
export LAST=2.0
export PAR1=78

seq $FIRST $STEP $LAST | parallel ./program pars $PAR1 {1} :::: - ::: {1..10}
```